# Is there a Spring interceptor that gets called before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to call a method before [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html).`attemptAuthentication()` is called (and before any other requests are handled in the app).

I tried calling the method in [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html).`preHandle()` but this is not triggered prior to `attemptAuthentication()` although it takes care of other types of requests.

**Is there a Spring interceptor that gets called before `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`?**

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are talking about the spring security filter chain.

Filters with this names should be invoked before `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

- FIRST
- CHANNEL_FILTER,
- CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER,
- SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER,
- LOGOUT_FILTER,
- X509_FILTER,
- PRE_AUTH_FILTER,
- CAS_FILTER,

See source code of `org.springframework.security.config.http.SecurityFilters` for more details.

---

But you can also use `before`:

```
<security:custom-filter ref="myFiler" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
```

Answer (score 3):

No - interceptors are part of Spring MVC which begins at `DispatcherServlet`.   Filters are called before servlets.

If you want to call something before `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` it will need to be a filter inserted before that filter.

Comment: Yes, Spring Security has filters, but the filters are called before DispatcherServlet which calls the Spring MVC interceptors.